# How can I delete an existing page in the Community Builder?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visualforce, community, delete, community-builder

At the Community Builder, how can I delete an existing page? I've been looking through the following UIs but didn't find a button, link or menu for that:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The delete-button is hidden in this menu here and you only see it, if you hover with the mouse over the page-name as shown below. It's the small trash-can icon.

[image]